# NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/compiler/gorm/GormEntityTransformation

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

I'm currently upgrading a rather large application to mongodb:5.0.1.RELEASE from mongodb:3.0.2 and I'm receiving the following exception when attempting to `grails package`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/compiler/gorm/GormEntityTransformation
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.gorm.GormTransformer.performInjection(GormTransformer.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.gorm.GormTransformer.performInjectionOnAnnotatedClass(GormTransformer.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.gorm.GormTransformer.performInjection(GormTransformer.java:61)
```

I followed these instructions for using the new mongodb plugin:
http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/latest/mongodb/manual/guide/gettingStarted.html


My Environment:

- OS: Windows 7
- JVM: 1.8.0_66
- Grails: 2.5.3
- Groovy: 2.4.4

I've created a **new/clean** project using grails 2.5.3 and upgraded it to the new version of the mongodb plugin and it worked perfectly, so I know the issue is somewhere with my configuration, but I'm running out of places to look.

My build configuration:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.8.1.RELEASE'

    compile "net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8"

    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"

    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"
    test("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:$seleniumVersion") { exclude 'xml-apis' }

    build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
    build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.2'
    runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
    runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.2'

    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.11'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.11'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.11'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.1'

    compile "com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.6"

    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'
    runtime 'xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01'

    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3'

    test 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2'

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
}

plugins {
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"
    compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"

    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime ':aws-sdk:1.9.22'

    compile(":mongodb:5.0.1.RELEASE");

    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
    compile ":fields:1.4"
    compile ":mail:1.0.7"

    compile ":phonenumbers:0.10"

    test "org.grails.plugins:geb:$gebVersion"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `compile "org.grails.plugins:mongodb:5.0.0.RC1"
    compile "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.0.2"` under dependencies

Comment: @SandeepPoonia I just tried as you suggested and I'm still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. I needed to also upgrade GORM rather than just the gorm mongodb plugin. This got me past the issue.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:5.0.1.RELEASE'
    ...
}
```

Comment: i am facing similar issue. i tired to the above driver but its giving similar error. mongodb 3.6 have changed alot related to aggregate queries. so its mandatory to change gorm version or need to write plain queries.

Comment: In short, the Grails version needs to match it's appropriate Gorm version which supports specific versions of the mongodb driver. To find the version of Gorm you'll need, take a look at the Gorm release notes. http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/#releaseNotes